# Redux match.params not working after updating state

Tags: arrays, reactjs, redux

I'm making a simple twitter style clone in ReactJS and Redux. I currently have it that when you click on a post on the main timeline, it takes you to a page that renders its replies by taking the user to <Link to={`/reply/${ling.id}`}> and using [this.props.match.params.id] to render the right one. That works great using the mock-data I start with.

However, when a user posts a new post - and that gets successfully rendered on the timeline - something goes wrong and the parameters don't match up, and if you click on the post that *should* be taking you to reply/3, it is instead rendering the reply with an id of 2.

I can still access the new post, but I have to go to reply/0 (instead of reply/7, which it should be), and if I console log things I can see that the correct data is there, it's just not rendering correctly.

The console shows this before I update state:

```
http://localhost:3000/reply/2 
LingReply.js:95 Should render ling # 2
LingReply.js:96 {id: 2 …}
```

But if I navigate to the same page after posting a new one, it does this:

```
LingReply.js:94 http://localhost:3000/reply/2
LingReply.js:95 Should render ling # 2
LingReply.js:96 {id: 1 …}
```

Here's the relevant code for the page that isn't working - am I missing something obvious?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Card, CardHeader, CardBody, CardFooter, Button } from "reactstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class LingReply extends Component {
  render() {
    const ling = this.props.lings.lings[this.props.match.params.id];
    console.log(window.location.href)
    console.log("Should render ling #", this.props.match.params.id)
    console.log(ling)

    return (
      <div key={ling.id}>
        <Card className="ling mb-3">
          <CardHeader>
            <span className="ling-date">{ling.lingLang}</span>
            <h3>
              {ling.userIcon} - {ling.userName}
            </h3>
          </CardHeader>
          <CardBody>{ling.lingBody}</CardBody>
        </Card>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    lings: state.lings,
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LingReply);
```

Here it is on my GitHub: https://github.com/gordonmaloney/Lingr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your messages are sort of linked or correlated to array indices, but then the other thought I had was maybe you were prepending the new messages, versus appending them. This places them at the beginning of the `lings` array instead of at the rear.

```
function LingsReducer(
  state = {
    lings,
  },
  action
) {
  console.log(action)

  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.POST_LING:
      return {
        ...state,
        lings: [{...action.payload}, ...state.lings], // <-- always added to front
      };
    default:
      console.log(state)
      return state
  }
}
```

You should invert the order.

```
function LingsReducer(
  state = {
    lings,
  },
  action
) {
  console.log(action)

  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.POST_LING:
      return {
        ...state,
        lings: [...state.lings, { ...action.payload }],
      };
    default:
      console.log(state)
      return state
  }
}
```

#### Update

I found where you are basically using array "indices" as id values. If you look in [NewLingComponent:L32-39](https://github.com/gordonmaloney/Lingr/blob/cc71f8570b871880ef651a20467bc4a4761415dc/src/components/NewLingComponent.js#L32-L39) you are using the array length to compute the next new `id`.

```
handleSubmit(values) {
  this.props.handleAddLing(
    values.newLingBody,
    values.newLingLang,
    values.newLingCorPref,
    this.props.lings.lings.length + 1 // <-- this
  );
}
```

- When array is empty, length is 0, you generate id 1
- When array length is 1, you generate id 2
- ... and so on

You may want to reconsider this and actually use a genuine GUID that sticks to the ling message data and isn't related to array indices as now you see this causes issues when you mutate the array (i.e. reorder, add or remove in the middle, etc...).

If you switched to using GUIDs then you will need to search for the match in `LingReply`.

```
class LingReply extends Component {
  render() {
    const { lings, match } = this.props;

    // I think I got the accesses correct here, but double check
    const ling = lings.lings.find(ling => ling.id === match.params.id);

    return (
      <div key={ling.id}>
        <Card className="ling mb-3">
          <CardHeader>
            <span className="ling-date">{ling.lingLang}</span>
            <h3>
              {ling.userIcon} - {ling.userName}
            </h3>
          </CardHeader>
          <CardBody>{ling.lingBody}</CardBody>
          <CardFooter>
            <ReplyCorrect content={ling.lingBody} />
            <Link to="/">
              <Button color="primary" outline>
                Post
              </Button>
            </Link>
          </CardFooter>
        </Card>

        <Replies ling={ling} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly it Drew - thanks!! But do you know why that is?? I can't work out why it would be taking the array index instead of the id?

Comment: @GordonMaloney You responded as I was adding my update and possible suggestion to remedy. Let me know if that all makes sense.

Comment: That does! Thank you so much Drew, will sort this - but even just inverting the order it's rendered in and appending the new one instead of prepending has worked as a dirty fix for the moment. Thanks - I had been tearing my hair out!